# Возможно ли реализовать такой виджет ANDROID

Tags: android, http, виджет

Добрый вечерок :) Имеется веб апи. Возможно ли сделать виджет который будет периодически отправлять запросы и мониторить инфу (периодичность 2-5минут)? Нужно именно виджет, если да, то как это лучше сделать , и какие могут быть подводные камни? 
Спасибо !:)

Comment: да, можно. Но запросы отправлять будет не виджет, а сервис. И после получения данных - обновлять виджет.

Comment: Легко делается. Гугли "Android Сервисы". Это процессы выполняющиеся в фоне. То есть, в фоне выполняется сервис и когда это нужно, обращается к виджету сообщая нужную информацию (если я правильно помню).